# Get most frequent value from SELECT result in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, count

I have 4 columns in my `[dbo].[game]` table:

- team_home_id
- team_away_id
- score_home
- score_away

By performing the following query, I am able to get as result the id's of the teams that **won** a game.

```
select 
    (case 
        when ([dbo].[game].[score_away] < [dbo].[game].[score_home]) 
           then [dbo].[game].[team_home_id] 
           else [dbo].[game].[team_away_id] 
     end) as winning_team_id
from 
    [dbo].[game]
```

Result example:

```
12
2
3
5
7
4
...
```

Is there any way to **count** and get the id of the team that **won** most games in the same query?

Comment: Use `count` and `group by`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that query and `group by winning_team_id` to get the number of wins. 
Then sort descending by the number of wins and get the top row.

```
select top 1 t.winning_team_id, count(*) counter from (
select 
    (case 
        when ([dbo].[game].[score_away] < [dbo].[game].[score_home]) 
           then [dbo].[game].[team_home_id] 
           else [dbo].[game].[team_away_id] 
     end) as winning_team_id
from 
    [dbo].[game] 
) t
group by t.winning_team_id
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
select winning_team_id, count(*)
from ( select (case  when ([dbo].[game].[score_away] < [dbo].[game].[score_home]) 
                          then [dbo].[game].[team_home_id] 
                     else [dbo].[game].[team_away_id] 
               end) as winning_team_id
       from     [dbo].[game] ) winners
group by winning_team_id
order by 2 desc
```

will give you a list sorted by the team id that won most games.

Use `select top 1` to get just the team that won most games,